# show the meta description of a Woocommerce product under the title in the product category overview

Tags: woocommerce, metadata, product, categories

I'm searching for an option to show the meta description of a Woocommerce product under the title in the product category overview. The code below in the functions.php of the theme repeat the SKU what the title is of the product. Wondering how to replace this with the meta description:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_sku_in_cart', 20, 1);
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_sku_in_cart( $template )  {
global $product;
$sku = $product->get_sku();
echo $sku;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by meta description? Do you mean product short description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a short description using `post->post_excerpt`. check below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_sku_in_cart', 20, 1);
function woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_sku_in_cart( $template )  {
    global $product;
    $sku = $product->get_sku();
    echo $sku;
    echo "</br>";
    echo get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to show the meta description from 2 text lines? The post _excerpt shows the fully description and that is to long. Something like: ' echo $product->post->post_meta_description;'

Comment: Got it: _yoast_wpseo_metadesc : The Avonic AV-CM60-IPX-BOX is a high-quality Box camera with 20x optical zoom and 60.7° horizontal field of view that delivers Full HD 1080p60 video.

Comment: Thanks a lot works perfect! It gives the category overview so much more body!